# derivative of square of dot product

Tags: derivatives, vectors

I've got:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \textbf{w}} \bigg( \textbf{x}^T\textbf{w}\bigg)^2$

when taking the derivative, does this result in

$2 (\underbrace{\textbf{x} ~\textbf{x}^T}_{\Sigma_x}) \textbf{w}^T$

or in the dot product of the $\textbf{x}$s

$2 (\underbrace{\textbf{x}^T ~\textbf{x}}_{scalar}) \textbf{w}^T$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{w}}\left(\vec{x}^T \vec{w} \right)^2 = 2 (\vec{x}^T \vec{w})\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{w}} (\vec{x}^T \vec{w}) =2 (\vec{x}^T \vec{w}) \vec{x}^T   = 2 \vec{w}^T (\vec{x} \vec{x}^T) $$
So it is the second one you wrote down. If you are differentiating with respect to vectors, it is sometimes nicer to use indices, so in this case $x^i = \vec{x}$, $\vec{w}= w^i$, then:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{w}}\left(\vec{x}^T \vec{w} \right)^2 =\sum_{i}  \frac{\partial}{\partial w^i}\left(\sum_j x^j w^j \right)^2 = \sum_i 2\left(\sum_j x^j w^j \right) \left(\sum_j x^j \underbrace{\frac{\partial w^j}{\partial w^i}}_{\delta_{ij}}\right) $$
$$ =  \sum_i 2 \left(\sum_j x^j w^j \right) x^i = 2 \sum_i \sum_j x^j w^j x^i=2 \vec{w}^T (\vec{x} \vec{x}^T)  $$
Which you can check is the same fairly easily.

Comment: One follow-up question: as your answer implies, could it actually be both of the above if I view $\vec{x} \vec{x}^T$ as a covariance matrix $\Sigma_x = \Sigma_x ^T$?  (This is actually what I want, since $\vec{x}$ is a data vector.)  It was pointed out to me that this should be OK, since the answer would still be a vector of the length $\vec{w}$.  I wasn't aware that the answer could actually be arbitrarily a matrix or scalar, as long as the final form is a vector of the same length.

Comment: Edited my answer, did some bad algebra at the first step. Should be corrected now. Accidentally wrote that $\vec{x} \vec{x}^T$ is a dot product, when it in fact its he matrix $\Sigma_x$ that you introduced,

Answer (score 3):

If $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf w$ are $n-$dimensional vectors, than

$(\mathbf x^T \mathbf w)^2=(x_1w_1+x_2w_2+\cdots +x_nw_n)^2=f^2$

is a scalar, and the [derivative of a scalar by a vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-vector) is the vector:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{w}}(f^2)=2f\frac{\partial f}{\partial  \mathbf{w}}=\begin{pmatrix}
2(x_1w_1+x_2w_2+\cdots +x_nw_n)x_1\\
2(x_1w_1+x_2w_2+\cdots +x_nw_n)x_2\\
\cdots\\
\cdots\\
2(x_1w_1+x_2w_2+\cdots +x_nw_n)x_n
\end{pmatrix}=
$$
$$=
2(x_1w_1+x_2w_2+\cdots +x_nw_n)
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\ \cdots\\
x_n
\end{pmatrix}=
2(\mathbf {x}^T\mathbf {w})\mathbf {x}
$$